# floating link hover background problem

Tags: css, navigation

on my navigation i have links then i have a link that is floated to the right. and when i hover over the right link i dont want anything to happen when i hover..but it adds a background right beside the last link on the left, because it's floated. how do i make no background appear on hover for the floated link? ive tried making a class then on :hover make background none but nothing changes.

i have a jsfiddle because its probably confusing lol

http://jsfiddle.net/r3bbm/

edit: also this doesnt happen in chrome, any other browser it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are floating the image inside the link, not the `<a>` tag. Try putting the `floatr` class on the `<a>` tag instead. Then make `.floatr:hover{background:none;}`

Comment: I tried that but when the float is on the a tag then the image gets pushed down

Comment: Give .floatr a -10px top margin.